# sed substitution or deleting string

Tags: sed

Thank you and what is wrong with this sed command?

```
sed 's/\\item\[\\textcircled\{\\tiny ?\}\]\: / /'
```

that should replace

```
\item[\textcircled{\tiny 1}]:
```

by nothing or one space and there can be other number than 1.

Comment: by default `sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions.. with BRE, `{}?` and few other characters are NOT special like you would expect... also, I think you wanted to use `.` instead of `?`

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/\\item\[\\textcircled{\\tiny \?[[:digit:]]\+}\]: / /' file` will do the trick?

Comment: Solve you problem in one thread.  Post original data, and not sample data.  You have 5 thread about the same last 24 hour.

Comment: I am sorry, it is solved by this question completly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\\item\[\\textcircled{\\tiny [0-9]+}\]: / /'
```

Above should do the trick, also in case your Input_file has multiple occurrences of same pattern then add `g` to above command to make substitution globally.

One more note, you need not to escape all characters in regex, always escape only those which have special meaning only. By escaping we will notify code not to take them as special ones, take them as literal characters only.

Comment: Perhaps the `+` should read `\+`? And the space before `  ``\?` or `  ``*`?